# symfony dotrine createNativeQuery emty result without entity

Tags: php, symfony

I have a problem; Thank you in advance for your help. I am using Symfony and when I make a SQL query, it freezes empty array.
But when I make this query to the database, 2 data come up.
SELECT *  FROM [category].[dbo].[categorylist] where title = '12345a14'

```
$query = "select * from category.dbo.categorylist where title = :title";
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
$nativeQuery = $this->entityManager->createNativeQuery($query, $rsm);
$params = [
    'title' => $title
];
$nativeQuery->setParameters($params);
$result = $nativeQuery->getResult();
```